# IIS is throwing pre-flight request CORS error

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, cors, iis-7

I have a .Net 6 Web API site that I am trying to reach from angular. The problem is IIS is throwing a Cors error no matter if I have the site online or not.

So the code that I have that enables Cors in my website are not of any relevance for this issue.

This is the error I am getting when making a simple login request. This error happens even if the site has been stopped. When I make this call in Postman I get a 500 error which is correct. When I make this call from my angular app, I still get a CORS issue.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://apidev.mysite.com//auth/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

Is there a setting in IIS that I need to look at in order to have my application only handle CORS?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not any setting in IIS but you can enable or allow from your code as

```
    var  MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy  =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                              "http://www.contoso.com");
                      });
});

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```